# Android Emulator Location Simulation not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

This is my first post, so I'm sorry if the formatting is a bit wonky.

I'm writing an application that is requiring me to use the emulator to change my location. I noticed when I called `fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`, the location is returned but it is `null`. This doesn't happen on my phone.

When the emulator started I got a warning about valorant anti-cheating software so I uninstalled valorant. It received the location sometimes whenever I ran my application after that.

I tried testing Google Maps on the emulator to see if it gets the location when I send it via the extended control panel but it is not updated in Google maps.

[Sending location via extended control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMCvz.png)

I tried:

- restarting the emulator
- deleting the emulator
- restarting my computer
- reinstalling android studio and user config

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7pjh.png)

How do I get location updates on google maps to work?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :) if you're new, you should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help getting started

Answer (score 0):

Switching between SDK 30 -> 29 and running API 29 fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Used SDK 28 instead of 30 and it's working correctly now.